# Obfuscate all query params except whitelisted

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm setting up a tracking script which tries to get not too much personal data. I don't want to store the value of all the params except a few.

Let's assume we have this variable coming from `window.location.search`:

```js
var search = '?utm_source=telegram&rel=twitter&password=nooooooo&utm_medium=phone';
```

I did try a few hours with regexes but I can't make it work:

```js
search.replace(/([?&][^=|^(utm_)]+=)[^&#]*/gi, '$1***')

// ?utm_source=telegram&rel=***&password=***&utm_medium=phone
```

But I would love to have this output:

```
?utm_source=telegram&rel=twitter&password=***&utm_medium=phone
```

So it should replace the values of all the parameters with `***` except for the parameters starting with `utm_` or being `rel`.

Comment: Didn't you do it upside down on your example? You told you want to hide details of `rel` and `utm_`, but on your desired output you just changed `password` and left the others untouched: `?utm_source=telegram&rel=twitter&password=***&utm_medium=phone`

Comment: Your desired output does not match your requirements. Also you are confusing group constructs with character classes.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the values of query strings? You may be doing something very wrong.

Comment: I would be *very* concerned if a password were ever included in a query string anywhere. No "may" about it, you are *definitely* doing something very wrong indeed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Marie This is a script which will run on other peoples websites. I don't have control over how they use their websites, so I just want to be sure that I don't get that data.

Julio: Indeed, fixed the question.

Comment: @revo, thanks for giving technical feedback! Could you provide an example or tutorial where the difference is explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with this:

`\b((?!rel|utm_)\w+)=[^&]+(?=&|$)`

Replace by: `$1=***`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GmKgBr/3/)**

**Explained:**

```
\b                  # Word boundary
((?!rel|utm_)\w+)   # A word that does not start with rel or utm_
=                   # literal =
[^&]+               # Any non & character repeated 1 or more.
                    # That will match the value
(?=&|$)             # Followed by & or end of line/string
```

Comment: Ai, I mad a mistake in the last sentence, fixed it. I want to replace every parameter value with `***` except the ones being `rel` and the ones starting with `utm_`.

Comment: Ok! I fixed the answer :)